# Formula language for a column view formula in Lotus Notes date calculation

Tags: lotus, lotus-formula

I have a view that has a date field within the view.  The user is asking that the first column of the view be categorized in the following manner and to have the titles as -   < 30 Days,  30 - 90 Days and > 90 Days.

Here is part of the formula that I have created:
@TextToTime(i_LastComDate)<@Adjust(@TextToTime( "Today" );0;0;-30;0;0;0)

Can anyone help me out in getting the calculation for a categorized column in the Notes view to display the documents as determined by the category that the document should be displayed?
I have thought about adding a field to the form but the view would allow for a dynamic display so it would appear correctly when the user may view the documents.

Thank you,
Jean

Answer (score 2):

@Today is a very bad idea to use in views as it causes the views to be permanently refreshed. There are a fiew best practices out there to handle your request. And there had been a discussion on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553003/how-do-i-select-all-documents-from-the-last-7-days)
A very good blog- entry is the one found [here](http://lotus-blogs.blogspot.de/2007/07/how-timedate-views-cause-performance.html).

If you ignore all of the advices, then the formula would be:

```
_diff := (@Today - @TextToTime(i_LastComDate)) / (24*3600);
@If( _diff > 90 ; "< 90 Days"; _diff > 30; "< 30 Days" ; "All the others" )
```

ATTENTION: To store a time- value in a textfield is always very bad practice (just say this because of your usage of @TextToTime, as it might be stored like 2013/04/23 or 23.04.2013 or any other variation, just because the client or server that saved the field had this as preference...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make agent, that will recalculate time difference at nights - as @Tode said, time/date formulas in views have well known and documented performance impact and are discouraged to be used!
Your view will be then categorized by:

```
@If( diff < 30; "< 30"; diff <= 90; "30 - 90"; "> 90")
```